# how can i print lines between 2 pattern using sed

Tags: sed, awk

How can i print lines between pattern1 and pattern2, i dont need lines between pattern1 and pattern3 though.

Please suggest the solution either in sed, awk.

I have case like this.

```
pattern1
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
pattern2
pattern1
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
pattern3
pattern1
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
pattern2
pattern1
blah blah blah 
blah blah blah
pattern3
```

Desire output:

```
pattern1
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
pattern2
pattern1
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
pattern2
```

Answer (score 5):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/pattern1/{:l N;/pattern3/b;/pattern2/!bl;p}' input
```

**Description**

```
/pattern1/{   # Match pattern1 and ...
:l N;         # start loop and read a line
/pattern3/b   # quit if pattern3 matches
/pattern2/!bl # loop until pattern2 matches
 p            # print all lines
```

**Output**

```
pattern1
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
pattern2
pattern1
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
pattern2
```

Comment: +1 I struggled with the solution you posted  for a long time; for some stupid reason I had an `d` instead of a `b` in my `/pattern3/`-part and couldn't figure out why it didn't work...

Comment: @sudo_O - its brief, not concise. Conciseness is the combination of brevity and clarity. Conciseness is a desirable quality in software, brevity is not.

Comment: @EdMorton, clarity is not the strongest suit of sed : )

Comment: @perreal I get where you're coming from but IMHO sed scripts are typically crystal clear when sed is used for what it should be used for which is simple substitutions on a single line. It's only when people employ the old, arcane sed language constructs that were necessary before awk was invented in the mid-1970s that sed scripts become obscure.

Comment: @EdMorton, I agree. But I also think this kind of simple loop and `N` constructs are OK, although at the limits of comprehension. Also `awk` scripts always look ugly to me.

Comment: @perreal - unlike sed you can write awk scripts in any style you like, just like with any other programming language so if there's a style you find ugly, just don't code in that style. The problem with the sed solution beyond simple incomprehensibility is the fact that the tiniest, conceptually simplest requirements change (e.g. don't print the pattern1->pattern2 record if it contains the word "foo") will mean a complete re-write of the script or be impossible without adding pipes and more tools.

Comment: It is unfortunate that the cute features of sed are getting unnoticed due to the availability of more advanced languages like awk & perl +

Comment: i tried the provided command but it is giving following error
bl: Event not found.

Comment: @dilip, you need to use single quotes around the sed script

Comment: @dilip, if you need double quotes, for example to interpolate variables, then do something like this: `sed -n "/pattern1/{:l N;/pattern3/b;/pattern2/"'!'"bl;p}" input`

Comment: @dilip are you using csh? You need to escape the escape the exclamation mark, better yet use bash.

Comment: @sudo_O, no i am not using csh.

Comment: What are you using then? The given script in single quotes won't cause a problem in `bash` unless the patterns you're actually trying to match contain quotes.

Comment: FWIW I get different error messages: `sed: -e expression #1, char 44: Extra characters after command` with GNU sed 3.0.2, and `Label too long: /pattern1/{:l N;/pattern3/b;/pattern2/!bl;p}` with /bin/sed on Solaris, both running under ksh93 and again under bash. Seems like there may be a portability issue!

Comment: @perreal, your given command sed -n "/pattern1/{:l N;/pattern3/b;/pattern2/"'!'"bl;p}" input worked for me. thanks a tone.

Answer (score 3):

One method:

```
$ awk '/pattern1/{s=1;f=1;s=NR}f{p[NR]=$0}/pattern3/{s=0}/pattern2/&&s{f=0;for(i=s;i<=NR;i++)print p[i]}' file
pattern1
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
pattern2
pattern1
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
pattern2
```

Comment: +1 that was trickier than I first thought; still struggling with my sed :-)

Comment: @FredrikPihl - this is not a simple substitution on a single line so this has not been an appropriate task for sed since the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

Comment: @EdMorton - you really seems to have a grudge against sed :-)

Comment: @FredrikPihl - no, sed is great, I use it almost every day. It's just unfortunate that people are still trying to use it in completely inappropriate ways and so confusing the heck out of newcomers to scripting and giving sed a bad name for obscure scripts. If only we could get rid of all those arcane sed language constructs and strip it down to just the 4 or 5 useful ones...

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '/pattern1/{f=!f;buf=""} f{buf = buf $0 ORS} /pattern2/{if(f)printf "%s",buf; f=0} /pattern3/{f=0}' file
pattern1
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
pattern2
pattern1
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
pattern2
```

To possibly help with comprehension, here's the above spread across a few lines and with wordier variable names:

```
awk '
/pattern1/ {
    found=!found
    buffer=""
}

found {
    buffer = buffer $0 ORS
}

/pattern2/ {
    if (found) {
        printf "%s",buffer
    }
    found=0
}

/pattern3/ {
    found=0
}
' file
```

Comment: The OP wasn't 100% clear on this but this will print from `pattern1` to `pattern3` for cases where `pattern3` is found between `pattern1` and `pattern2`

Answer (score 1):

I got lost among my hold-spaces in a pure sed solution; so here is an alternative

```
$ tac input | sed '/pattern3/,/pattern1/d' | tac
pattern1
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
pattern2
pattern1
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
pattern2
```

Comment: This won't quit work for cases when `pattern3` falls between `pattern1` and `pattern2`. Check out @perreal answer for a nice `sed` solution.

Comment: yeah yeah yeah, rub it in. I almost had the solution he posted but I fumbled on the finishing line...

Comment: Haha ;) I have to agree with @EdMorton that as soon as you want to do something none trivial `sed` can be a headache.

Comment: +1: I think this is the simplest and clearest solution of those listed here.

Comment: @ruakh - the solution posted here employs negative logic. Try enhancing that in any way and you will soon find yourself embroiled in double-negatives. Besides that, just try some conceptually trivial enhancement like printing a count of the number of matched blocks.

Comment: @EdMorton: Granted, but your concerns are easily addressed with a small change, such as `tac input | sed '/pattern2/,/pattern1/' | tac`.

Comment: @ruak please show the tweak to print the number of records or to not include the line containing pattern1 or to not print the record if it contains the word "foo" or do just about anything else.

Comment: @EdMorton: I'll show you mine if you show me yours. How would you tweak your code to translate the input into French? (AWK is, of course, a more powerful and more language than sed. This hardly seems like a reason to object to a straightforward sed script -- especially when you have no straightforward AWK script to present instead.)

Comment: @ruaka the reason this may seem the clearest is because it does not do the same thing as the other 3 answers, this answer is flawed, see my first comment.

Comment: @ruakh - I posted a straightforward awk script already. It finds the start pattern and sets a flag and inits a buffer. When the flag is set it adds the current line to the buffer. If/when it finds an end pattern it prints the buffer if necessary and clears the flag. Couldn't be much simpler, and easily extensible to any real potential requirements change (which would not include translating to French).

Comment: @sudo_O: I saw your comment, but I *don't* think this answer is flawed. The original question is rather vague, but going from the example, this seems like a valid interpretation.

Comment: @EdMorton: Sorry, but I don't think your AWK script is straightforward!

Comment: @ruakh - and you feel that the working (in some implementations) sed solution of `sed -n '/pattern1/{:l N;/pattern3/b;/pattern2/!bl;p}' input` IS more straightforward? OK, whatever you're happy with...

Comment: @EdMorton: What? You seem to have gotten confused somehow. That sed script is one of the answers that I think is *not* straightforward. It's as bad as your AWK script. The answer that we're discussing is `tac input | sed '/pattern3/,/pattern1/d' | tac`, though personally I think that `tac input | sed -n '/pattern2/,/pattern1/p' | tac` is even better.

Comment: @ruakh neither `tac input | sed '/pattern3/,/pattern1/d' | tac` nor `tac input | sed -n '/pattern2/,/pattern1/p' | tac` work because they'd both fail (but in different ways) when pattern2 occurs after a pattern1->pattern3 block but before a subsequent pattern1 so let's compare apples to apples by looking at the sed and awk solutions that work given that (IMHO very likely) input.

Comment: Gentlemen, this is what I like about SO, great minds working together to provide solutions to interesting problems. I admire both of you but please drop this now and move on to more important problem-solving issues :-)

Comment: @EdMorton: Garbage in, garbage out. According to the question, the entire input consists of pattern1->pattern2 blocks and pattern1->pattern3 blocks. The question does not indicate what the correct behavior *would* be when the input contains other extraneous data, so you have no basis for saying that these sed scripts would "fail" whereas your script would not. Perhaps it's your script that behaves wrongly, and one of these would be correct.